# How to convert Map<String, Object> to Map<Key, Value> in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

**I have this Map of String, Object I want it to be flattened so the result is Map of Key, Value**

```
void main(){


    var li = {"qotd_date":"2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00","quote":{"id":61869,"dialogue":false,"private":false,"tags":[],"url":"https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--","favorites_count":1,"upvotes_count":0,"downvotes_count":0,"author":" Wael Ghonim ","author_permalink":"wael-ghonim","body":"The power of the people is greater than the people in power."}};


    print(li);

}
```

**Current Output :**

```
{qotd_date: 2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00, quote: {id: 61869, dialogue: false, private: false, tags: [], url: https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--, favorites_count: 1, upvotes_count: 0, downvotes_count: 0, author:  Wael Ghonim , author_permalink: wael-ghonim, body: The power of the people is greater than the people in power.}}
```

**Expected Output I want is**

```
{"qotd_date":"2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00","id":61869,"dialogue":false,"private":false,"tags":[],"url":"https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--","favorites_count":1,"upvotes_count":0,"downvotes_count":0,"author":" Wael Ghonim ","author_permalink":"wael-ghonim","body":"The power of the people is greater than the people in power."};
```

***It is just like flattening the Map. Please help me get out of this?***

Comment: what do you need? why don't you use something like this ? print("value: ${li['qotd_date']}");

Comment: first, it's Map<String, dynamic> probably, second this Map is already like Map<Key,Value>. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Show was is the current result, and what you expect.

Comment: @diegoveloper but I want to access the subparts in the second Pair Which has another Map as Value

Comment: @mathronaut But I want all the Map as a single Map<Key, Value> type as I Mentioned now in the question. Sorry for my incomplete explanation. Thank You..

Comment: @JulienLachal Yes I have edited the question and that was what I am expecting as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, encode as json:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> li = {
    "qotd_date": "2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00",
    "quote": {
      "id": 61869,
      "dialogue": false,
      "private": false,
      "tags": [],
      "url": "https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--",
      "favorites_count": 1,
      "upvotes_count": 0,
      "downvotes_count": 0,
      "author": " Wael Ghonim ",
      "author_permalink": "wael-ghonim",
      "body": "The power of the people is greater than the people in power."
    }
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> flattened = {};

  li.removeWhere((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      flattened.addAll(value);
    }
    return value is Map;
  });

  flattened.addAll(li);

  print(jsonEncode(flattened));
}
```

Output:

```
{"id":61869,"dialogue":false,"private":false,"tags":[],"url":"https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--","favorites_count":1,"upvotes_count":0,"downvotes_count":0,"author":" Wael Ghonim ","author_permalink":"wael-ghonim","body":"The power of the people is greater than the people in power.","qotd_date":"2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @MehmetEsen solution, all you really need to add is [jsonEncode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html), the work of jsonEncode is to convert object to a JSON string

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main(){

var li = {"qotd_date":"2019-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00","quote":{"id":61869,"dialogue":false,"private":false,"tags":[],"url":"https://favqs.com/quotes/wael-ghonim/61869-the-power-of--","favorites_count":1,"upvotes_count":0,"downvotes_count":0,"author":" Wael Ghonim ","author_permalink":"wael-ghonim","body":"The power of the people is greater than the people in power."}};


print(jsonEncode(li));
```

}